# Migration from MS Access 2003 to MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013, ms-access-2003

I work for a company where we likely going to update from Access2003 to Access2013.
Can you please brief me about the issues i'll face. Related links for my research will be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Biggest pain for us was the removal of the workgroup security feature from Access. If you use a custom .mdw file for administering security in your application, you are going to lose this and therefore lose control over who can modify database objects (Forms, Reports etc). Seem to recall that it was a pain converting these secured DBs - I think we had to transfer ownership of all objects to Admin first.

Answer (score 0):

Except for custom commandbars and ADP projects, it is usually just to ask Access 2013 to upgrade the old database.

Why don't you just try?

Comment: We have all the VBA code attached to the database. Is there any issues we are going to face with the code?

Comment: Probably not. But again - why not just go ahead?